# Fill in sequential numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have listed out sequential numbers `(ie. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13...)` in column A on excel, and I have the start and end numbers for a certain event *(eg. start number: 3, end number: 8)*. I want to put a "1" from 3-8 and "0" for the rest using a formula. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
=--AND(A1>=$E$1,A1<=$E$2)
```

[image]